# Unity Point light shining through objects at distance

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I am trying to make a type of street-light-ish thing and everything is working well, except that the point light I am using as the main source for the light is shining through the objects around it, but only at a large  distance.

As I get closer, the light slowly fades back to what it should be like. (I have asked this question on Unity answers, but i figured it wouldn't hurt to ask here, too).

What the light looks like standing near it:

[image: What the light looks like standing near it[1]]

[image]

Comment: FYI i can partially solve this issue by using a spot light instead of a point light, but i lose the cool effect of there being an object emitting the light. (also i'm curious as to why it does this with a point light)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably the fact that the shadow distance is set to a value below the distance where the light reappears.

I suggest you should bake the light if you want to keep the shadow even at distance. This happens in AAA titles aswell. Either you try to work around it, or bake the shadow.

[Lightmapping Quickstart](https://docs.unity3d.com/351/Documentation/Manual/Lightmapping.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty late to answer this question, but to anyone else having this problem just as I encountered it myself: go to the light source you're having trouble with >inspector> Shadow type > and set your shadows (which are probably set to "No shadows") either on hard or on soft shadows, depends on what you like. If you still have the same issue, set Strength to 1.

This fixed it for me :)